# TestNG execution report shows PASS count but extent report shows Zero

Tags: testng, extentreports

I am facing a weird issue where TestNG execution report gives the number of passed test cases and Extent report shows pass count as zero. I am using Extent 5.0.9. Attaching screenshot for reference.
[Pass count shown as zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Bw0.png)

[TestNG count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfu2z.png)